# I've been on C# course and struggle to remember things?

Tags: c#

I'm an apprentice and I've been on a couple of training courses in C#, I understood the concept of c# programming and covered inheritance etc, but when I've came to code for my coursework "I've got to make a shopping basket and save the contents into a .txt" I just seems to not know what to do, as if I've got no idea how to program. I've got a copy of the end product apart from it's altered so we can't copy it whole, so I've just been taking code and not really understanding everything that's doing on.
I just seem as if I don't want to program as if I'm in a different mind set, I just seem to go blank at the thought of creating a simple program from scratch and have no Idea where to start? Any one got any ideas for help ? :) thx

Comment: Fiddle with code. Debug. Learn by trial and error. It's like studying a foreign language. Noone learns it (successfully) just by sitting in an armchair, skim-reading a dictionary.

Comment: So simply look, cover ,write ,check ? Should I download some sample code and pull that apart and see how that works ? :) thanks

Comment: Yes absolutely. The adage is: don't learn to program - program to learn. Of course you should still balance it and don't go all cowboy with no theory backup. But the "conservative" approach schools condition us to take does not work the best in this field.

Comment: See http://youtu.be/TL05Es8LVAQ for inspiration ;) It's not about programming, obviously, but the principle holds whether it's learning martial arts, playing chess, studying a foreign language or programming. Dead patterns do nothing for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learning a language (eg, C#) and learning to program are two separate things.  Of course, it's easier to do the latter if you know the former :)

But, just knowing the ins and outs of a language isn't enough to be a programmer.  Programming is also about problem solving (and eventually code maintenance).

Like others have mentioned:  If the problem you're trying to solve seems difficult to crack, try breaking it down into logical sub-problems.  If that is still tricky don't worry.  This comes with time.  You could instead try solving smaller problems.

You only learn to be a programmer by programming.  It doesn't matter in which language.  Technically you don't even need a programming language!  You could write down a list of instructions in plain English and that would also be a program!

Answer (score 1):

Try to break your task into small pieces, just create a list of tasks you have to do and one by one go coding them and then integrate together. Start with a simple class with one task at the start, add methods and properties, refer OOP's concepts on how to use them and read about topics which you need to implement in project and try out some examples. Usually big task seems daunting but if you break into small things you will be able to do it quickly.